# How to implement a Queue in java?

Tags: java

I'm looking to implement a Queue in java using java.util.Queue and java.util.LinkedList.

The Queue should be included in Workshop. Note that the workshop should have the methods add and remove.

I've done this:

```
public interface workshop {   
public void add(E e);
public void remove();
```

}

```
public class Aqueue implements workshop {

private LinkedList<E> work = new LinkedList<E>();

public Aqueue() {
    work = new LinkedList<E>();
}

@Override
public void add(E e) {
    list.addLast(E);
}

@Override
public void remove() {
        list.remove(0);
    }
```

However, I haven't used java.util.Queue and is my class equeue even a Queue?

I've been searching for hours, but every Queue I found is either an Array or made completely from scratch.

Comment: "I haven't used java.util.Queue " - Of course you have - `LinkedList` implements `Deque`, which is a sub-interface of `java.util.Queue`.

Comment: Is this code correct then?

Comment: Side note: class names and interface names should be capitalised - so `Workshop`. Sounds nitpicky, but code that doesn't follow style guidelines is harder to read and you'll get fewer good answers.

Comment: Surely you need to `implement Queue`?

Comment: `Queue<Foo> kyoo = new LinkedList<>()`

Comment: As mentioned by Eran, `LinkedList` implements `Deque`, hence, you should look up the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and check the methods you should use.

Comment: take a look at this explanation of the  Queue interface by Jenkov
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/queue.html